# How to add padding to inside of the plot in plotly (python)

Tags: plotly-python

I have draw such a figure in plotly (python). [image]

As you can see, very small part from the right side of the figure is hidden. How can I enlarge right side of this chart that green numbers can be seen clearly? When I have large numbers in color green only their first two numbers can be seen. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by manually setting the range for your x-axis so that there is enough space for the number to be shown. You can do that by updating your code to include a line similar to this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(range=[1.5, 4.5])
```